# Getting a value from the parent scope to the child scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm very new to Angular and cannot seem to pass the id of a post to be deleted to the delete controller. Here's the HTML of the parent:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-fab btn-raised btn-danger btn-trash"
                ng-dialog="/static/templates/risks/delete-risk.html"
                ng-dialog-controller="DeleteRiskController as vm"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
```

And the child form in a separate template file:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="vm.destroy(THEPLACEWHEREINEEDTHEID)">
    <div class="form-group delete">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this?</p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger">
          Delete
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that, while in the parent scope I can put this expression: `{{ risk.id }}`, in the child scope, it's empty. All I need to do for a working delete function is to have that risk.id value as the parameter in the function above.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent scope by simply doing: `{{$parent.risk.id}}`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, though I'm not sure why. As I say, in the risk.html template, `{{ risk.id }}` works fine, but in the delete.html template controlled by the `DeleteRiskController`, it doesn't print anything.